# Git Merge Issue: No common ancestor

Tags: git, merge, rebase

In our environment we have dev and feature branches. Recently, I went to merge dev into my feature branch before I push my changes.

My issue is that it seems all files that have been updated in the dev branch since my last pull are marked as conflicts, instead of simply pulling in the changes. Same thing for files I've changed but have not been touched by any other commits in dev.

I originally thought it might be a whitespace issue, but I've asked GIT to ignore whitespace with the various flags available.

I've also noticed that when I do a 3 way diff, it shows nothing as a common ancestor. So, I think someone might have borked the branch with a rebase.

In any case, does anyone have an idea of the easiest strategy to merge at this point?

Comment: The first step would be figuring out why `git` thinks there is no common ancestor between your two branches. `git log --all --graph` might help with this, or `gitk` or any other repository visualization tool...

Comment: @twalberg everything in a git repo has the root commit as its ancestor, and so there is no such thing as "no common ancestor".

Comment: @Kaz That is not true. It is entirely possible to have two or more distinct parent-less "root" commits within a single repository with `git` - maybe not with CVS or SVN or ..., but it's definitely possible in Git. So you could say everything has *a* root commit in its history, but there isn't necessarily a unique "*the* root commit". And, even if that's not the case in Nixx's specific situation, `git` obviously thinks it might be...

Comment: @twalberg Could you create this situation in a single repo with some combination of `git` commands starting with `git init`? Or is this just a situation caused by pulling objects from a remote repo?

Comment: @Kaz Yes - try `mkdir foo; cd foo; git init; touch file1; git add file1; git commit -m first; git checkout --orphan sidebranch master; touch file2; git add file2; git commit -m second; git log --all` and note that neither of the two commits have parents - they are both "root" commits on two separate branches. It can also happen with various forms of `git subtree` operations, or by `git push`ing an unrelated branch into a repository, or various other ways...

Comment: @Kaz Actually, you'll need to do `git log --all --pretty=raw` at the end to see the parentage info. Try adding additional commits to either branch and possibly use `git log --all --graph` (or `gitk`), as well...

Comment: For those curious, the dev branch was moved. A new branch that was imported from SVN took its place. Looks like in SVN that branch was similar to the dev branch, but not quite the same.